# IJulia plot One Liner

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, julia

I am trying to switch from Mathematica to IJulia for data exploration, and I was wondering if there's a n analogue for the following Mathematica one-liner:

```
ListPlot[Import["/tmp/output.tsv"], Joined -> True]
```

[image: ListPlot]

`output.tsv` is a tab delineated list of (X,Y) pairs

Here's a lame attempt:

```
In [1]: using Gadfly; plot(readdlm("/tmp/output.tsv", '\t', Float64))

no method plot(Array{Float64,2},)
at In[1]:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gadfly will accept arrays, but you need to specify the `x` and `y` values. Also, you need to pass an aesthetic.

```
julia> a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

julia> plot(a)
ERROR: no method plot(Array{Int64,2})

julia> plot(x=a[1,:], y=a[2,:], Geom.line)
```

Here is a screenshot from REPL (not IJulia):

[image: repl screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have to read it into a dataframe (DataFrames.readtable), since that's what Gadfly operates on. Other plotting packages such as Winston operate on raw data, but since you are reading structure data anyway, the DataFrames approach is probably best.

Comment: Okay, so when I try `using Gadfly, DataFrames; plot(readtable("/tmp/output.tsv", separator = '\t', header = false))` julia throws `ArgumentError("Empty array is not allowed.")`. Should I be breaking up the DataFrame from `readtable` into `x` and `y` components?  The Gadfly docs call this a *heretical* pattern...